# Eclipse PyDev ignores __init__, leading to unresolved module import error

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

It is unclear how to properly structure our PyDev projects/packages within our git repo so that absolute imports work out as [they should](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html). This results in Eclipse throwing an "unresolved import" error that I don't understand.

Currently, the repo looks like this:

```
REPO/ [repo master]  # Set as source folder (PYTHONPATH)
    package_A/       # Set as source folder (PYTHONPATH)
       __init__.py   # from foo import some_func
       __main__.py   # Absolute import required
       foo.py        # some_func()
    package_B        # Set as source folder (PYTHONPATH)
       __init__.py
       __main__.py
       bar.py
__init__.py          # Empty
```

`package_A/__init__.py` looks like this:

```
from foo import some_func
```

Now I go to `package_A/__main__.py` and want to import `some_func()` from `foo`:

```
from foo import some_func       # works
from package_A import some_func # unresolved import error in Eclipse
# The latter case should work due to the initial import in __init__
```

According [this source](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html), the second option should work. The fact that it doesn't means that due to some reason, the content of `package_A/__init__.py` doesn't have any effect. What is my mistake?

What is the root cause of the above-mentioned unresolved import error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import `package_A`, it should not be set as a source folder itself.

I.e.: only `REPO` should be marked as a source folder (that's the only entry that should be in the PYTHONPATH).

Note that the `from foo import some_func` will not work in that case... So, you can either write an absolute import `from package_A.foo import some_func` or a relative import: `from .foo import some_func`.